# Selenium: Connection refused after first successful connection with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda, google-chrome-headless

After succesfully deploying an AWS Lambda + REST API Selenium package with Python 3.6 and testing it -HTTP request or directly from the Lambda dashboard- I'm unable to execute the script a second time and the error `[Errno 111] Connection refused"` is shown.

The only way I can fix this is by changing random configs in the dashboard, such as the allocated memory, PATH or concurrency settings. In other words, I have to manually redeploy the entire Lambda package in order to get it working again.

I've googled for some hours now and it seems like the error is related to the port already being in use, but my Python scripts ends with `driver.close()` before the return command so I can't see where this is coming from. Is there a way to manually redeploy the lambda package every time my script is executed? Or even better: How do I  fix this?

Here are all of the options I use:

```html
hrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data')
chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1280,1000')
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
chrome_options.add_argument('--v=99')
chrome_options.add_argument('--single-process')
chrome_options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir')
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36')
chrome_options.binary_location = os.getcwd() + "/bin/headless-chromium"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb')
```

Comment: Are you using selenium to make an API request? Is the code above part of lambda function itself?

Comment: The code above is part of the start of the lambda_function.py file, not part of the lambda_handler function itself. The API request is handled by AWS's API gateway and it works flawlessly, as I've tested it with simpler functions (printing the message sent by the client, and printing the current time)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `driver.quit()`, as `driver.close()` is generally not sufficient to terminate a `WebDriver` session.

The `driver.close` function only closes the browser window that is currently in focus. The `driver.quit` function calls the internal `driver.dispose` function, closes all browser windows, and then gracefully terminates the `WebDriver` session.